# Losing network operator on Samsung Galaxy SIII mini

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, calls, mobile-network, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

For some time now (I think it's from the latest Android update) I have this problem,
that time to time (on daily basis) people can not reach me, like I would lose connection to the Network.

I get an SMS after some time about all the calls I did miss. Sometimes I have a hard time to call as well.

I did call my operator, and they didn't had any report like this so far, and I did call Samsung service, and they didn't know about this issue, so I guess is on my side.

If you have any idea what would the problem be let me know.

Comment: Do the callers get any "error", like e.g. line busy, or your device currently being unreachable -- or do they get the feeling you simply don't pick up the phone? I had the latter case from time too with my old phone (no ring, no missed call, but callers got to the mailbox and then I got the SMS immediately thereafter). Did not (yet?) happen with my new device, so it could be something specific to either the device or its software. Though I never had the problems you describe initiating a call.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem, and it was caused by physical activity making the SIM card coming slightly loose, just enough so that the phone couldn't read it reliably. Try turning the phone off completely, removing the SIM card, reinserting the SIM card, and then restarting the phone.

If that makes the problem go away (at least for a few days), then it probably is the SIM card coming loose: maybe that specific phone is on the largest extreme of manufacturing tolerance, and the SIM card is at the smallest extreme. In this case, a little paper inserted alongside the SIM card, on the side without the contacts, could provide a more lasting fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my S3 mini. Two or three times a week the GSM/Edge/3G signal strength indicator is at zero and I cannot make or recieve calls, despite being in a good signal area. A simple power down and power up restores the connection, reports good SSI and the backlog of SMS and voicemail calls start coming.